# get elementId from event in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function barvaInfo(event) {

$(document).ready(function(){
var nid = window.event.srcElement.id;
}
```

this works in IE but not in FF. Can i use jquery for this? i try with JQuery event api but then i do not know how to get ID from it.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to get an ID of an element when the DOM finishes loading. For which event are you trying to get the srcElement?

Comment: The `window.event` is specific to IE. Other browsers have a parameter on their event handlers that gets an `event` object when an event actually occurs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using jQuery, you'll need to assign a parameter to your event handlers, then pass the argument to your function on each event.

You may also want to call it from the context of the element that received the event.

```
     // some mouseover event handler
$('div').mouseover( function( e ) { 
    barvaInfo.call( this, e )
});

function barvaInfo( event ) {
       // element that originated the event
    var nid = event.target.id;

    // in this function, because we're using .call() to invoke it, 
    //    "this" will reference the element that invoked the handler
}
```

Comment: what if i need it on mousover not on click

Comment: @senzacionale: Then you assign a `mouseover()` event instead. I'll update my answer, but it is the same principle. EDIT: Updated my answer to use `mouseover` instead of `click`.

Comment: ...you should also not that `mouseenter` may be more appropriate for your situation. It will only fire the handler on the targeted element, and none of its descendants.

Answer (score 2):

The `event object` is normalized through jQuery for you and is passed into each `event handler`:

```
$('someelement').bind('click', function(event) { 
    var nid = this.id; // event.target.id
});
```

within the handler, `this` refers to the dom node of invocation. So `this.id` would address the `id` of the element. Alternative, the event object owns a property called `target` which also represent the element.

**edit**

As `patrick dw` pointed out, `this` will always be a reference to the node to which the event handler was bound to. `event.target` is exactly what it says, the element which is the actual target. See comments for an example link.

Comment: `this` and `event.target` are not necessarily the same element.

Comment: event is generic type. i know i can use class or something else bit i want to use it on generic element.

Comment: @patrick: ay, yes sir. I forgot a second about nested nodes and bubbling. I'll correct myself.

Comment: thx for answer i try $('div').bind('mouseover', function(event) { 
    var nid = this.id; 
});

Comment: but i get now 30 ids instead of one which i am mouseover